# How to obtain a space between two elements in DataTable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I am printing the data from `ViewModel` into `DataTable` in the following way, but how to obtain a `space` between `@item.FirstName` and `@item.LastName` so that the output can be of the form `FirstName LastName`? At present, I am getting the `Name` as `FirstNameLastName`. Ex: `MarkStevens`. I want to print it as `Mark Stevens`.

```
@if(Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="Name">Name</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
}
else
{
    <h3 style="text-align:center">No Records Found</h3>
}
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @(if (item.UserId != null)
                {
                    @item.FirstName @item.LastName
                }
                else
                {
                    @item.OtherUser
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **@Html.Raw** helper which means, you render whatever inside without any html encoding like space or string:

```
@item.FirstName @Html.Raw(" ")  @item.LastName
```

If you want html, you can also use a simple non-breaking spaces:

```
@item.FirstName &nbsp; &nbsp;  @item.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

How about string format the output: `$"{@item.FirstName} {@item.LastName}"`

Answer (score 0):

use `string.Format.` i feel this is very clean approach.

```
  string.Format("{0} {1}", @item.FirstName,@item.LastName)
```